# Apply Force in Box2d correctly

Tags: box2d

I have a body and I want to move it by applying a force on it. So In each frame update event I apply force like this:

```
body->ApplyForceToCenter(100 * body->GetMass() * b2Vec2(vel.x, vel.y), true);
```

But I have a serious problem here. As I have to update Box2d world with constant time step

> We also don't like the time step to change much. A variable time step
>   produces variable results, which makes it difficult to debug. So don't
>   tie the time step to your frame rate (unless you really, really have
>   to). [[see here]](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html)

I wrote this code to update physics world:

```
void Box2dManager::update(float dt)
{
    static const double step = 1.0/60.0;
    static double accumulator = 0.0;

    // TODO check do we need this?
    // max frame time to avoid spiral of death
    if ( dt > 0.25 )
        dt = 0.25;

    accumulator += dt;

    while (accumulator >= step)
    {
        m_world.Step(step, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
        accumulator -= step;
    }
}
```

The result is that the movement of the body becomes choppy when I apply force in different directions using a sneaky joystick, no matter even if it moves slow or fast. And when I update world by time step of my frame rate (`dt` function argument), only then the movement becomes smooth. How can we explain this? And how can we fix this?

Also here this is not only the problem of moving choppy, but there is another issues too, because actually I am not applying constant force as FPS is not constant and I apply force in each frame only once. So during different periods I apply the same force with the same time interval (world step).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two solutions, either we should use smaller step like `1 / 300.0` or we should do some smoothing like this: http://www.unagames.com/blog/daniele/2010/06/fixed-time-step-implementation-box2d

Here areanother good articles:

1. http://siondream.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/
2. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step
3. http://kirbysayshi.com/2013/09/24/interpolated-physics-rendering.html

Comment: I know that is an old question, but I have the same problem. I checked the http://www.unagames.com/blog/daniele/2010/06/fixed-time-step-implementation-box2d implementation, the only thing that I don't fully understand is the smoothing part. Are we re-setting the position in the physics world after the world simulation because they are wrong ? :S